# How to connect a capacitive sensor to a speaker to play a sound

Tags: microcontroller

I am doing a home project in electronics for the first time with my friend. The aim is to connect three capacitive sensors to a speaker and depending on which one we press the speaker will output different sounds i.e. classical music in one.

Knowing how to connect just one capacitive sensor to a speaker to play a sound is a great starting point. I have very little idea about electronics and do not know where to start or how I could even program this, or how much it would even cost.

Would it be easier to design a simple speaker or buy one? What microcontroller do I use?

I do not need serious, in-depth answers; I would just like the general idea of how it could work.

Comment: You need several things to do this: a source of the sounds, and audio amplifier to drive the speaker, and a means for the capacitive sensor to control the system.

Comment: This question is too broad for a single answer. Make several questions out of it. The Arduino envirnonment provides solutions for capacitive sensing and playing sounds and music. I suggest to focus on capacitive sensors first. An audio amplifier can be bought to reduce the complexity a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner, broad support is the most important factor when picking a microcontroller. So, go with an Arduino. Probably an *Uno* since it is very widely used.

Then you need a simple amplifier and a speaker. You can buy simple little amps for less than $10. Scrounge a speaker from a broken device.

I just bought [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y4ZBNB2) for fooling around in the lab. Two for $10.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 groups of music players in the Arduino world:

1. Low MCU power/frequency. These solutions can only read (mono) WAV files from a SD card, because this file format does not need any data processing. So the job for the MCU is reading the audio sample values one by one and send them to a PWM or DAC channel to produce analog audio signals. If the sounds are available as MP3, they must first be converted. Some of this systems cannot even read subfolders on the SD card. This is an example for this type of solution: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/LithiumION/arduino-mp3-player-3959db
2. Using a dedicated MP3 converter module in combination with a simple Arduino. Here the sounds are MP3 encoded on the SD card and the additional module does all the math to reconstruct the analog sound in good quality. Again the Arduino has the simple job of being a data pump without real computation. Here is an example: https://maker.pro/arduino/projects/how-to-use-the-dfmini-player-mp3-module-with-arduino
3. Using a powerful MCU, it is possible to do the decoding math inside the Arduino. This is a bit advanced but offers many options. An introduction can be found here: https://learn.adafruit.com/native-mp3-decoding-on-arduino

The sound quality of the first group is very limited but may be good enough for a toy or fun device. The other solutions can reach acceptable quality, just a bit more noise than a good cell phone provides.

Since you want to play dedicated sounds triggered on hardware events, have a look how flexible the solution is, regarding functions like *start*, *stop* and *play* a dedicated title.

**EDIT:**
A very cheap (< $1) capacitive sensor for Arduinos can be implemented this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foR5wT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The sensor has "medium" sensitivity, will say, it detects direct touch very good (+40 in value) and with thick paper between sensor and finger acceptable (+10 in value). It is not a proximity or through glass detector.

It has very low noise (+/- 1 count) and low sensor impedance. So it is not susceptible to mains EM field. For a first test the ESD protection can be skipped and input A1 can directly be connected to the sensor area.

Some Arduinos have buit in capacitive sensing hardware and this should be used preferred if available.

This is the Arduino source code to use the above circuit. It takes 5 measurements per second and sends the values to a serial monitor or plotter.

```cpp
// Simple capacitive sensor for Arduinos, Aug 14, 2022, coded by Jens@E42
//
// This code was written for Mega AVR series MCUs and tested on
// atMega32U4, one setup with Teensy 2.0, one setup with 
// Arduino Leonardo.
//
// The code implements a software charge pump using a charge 
// collecting capacitor of 3.3 nF between two MCU pins, 
// where one of them must be an ADC input.
// The sensing function delivers a value if not touched and 
// a far bigger one if touched. 
// The reading in the test circuit was idle 64 and directly 
// touched 100.
//
// tested example:
// capacitor 3.3 nF connected between A0 and A1
// sensor wire connected to A1
//
#define PUMP_PIN_1    A0    // must be an ADC capable pin
#define SENS_PIN_1    A1    // any other pin

#define PUMP_CYCLES   5     // charge pump cycles, more gives a little better resolution

// needs 70 us on 16 MHz Teensy 2.0, 60 us of that used by analogRead()
// needs 250 us on 16 MHz Leonardo, 100 us of that used by analogRead()
// same MCU, same frequency but much faster Teensy I/O Lib
word readCapSensor_1 (void) {
  // 1. discharge sampling capacitor by connecting 
  //  PUMP_PIN_1 and SENS_PIN_1 to VCC
  pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PUMP_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (SENS_PIN_1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (PUMP_PIN_1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds (3);   // needed safe discharge time for 3.3 nF
  // 2. release capacitor, becomes floating
  pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, INPUT);
  pinMode (PUMP_PIN_1, INPUT);
  // 3. critical timing for the next about 14 us (Teensy)
  noInterrupts();
  for (byte i = 0; i < PUMP_CYCLES; i++) {
    // 4. short low pulse at SENS_PIN_1 charges sensor wire and sensor
    pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite (SENS_PIN_1, LOW);
    pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, INPUT);
    // 5. connect other capacitor end to VCC, 
    //  transfer a part of the charge to the capacitor
    digitalWrite (PUMP_PIN_1, HIGH);
    pinMode (PUMP_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (PUMP_PIN_1, INPUT);
    // 6. release capacitor, becomes floating again
  }
  // end of critical timing
  interrupts();
  // capacitor has collected charge with pos at PUMP_PIN_1 and neg at SENS_PIN_1
  // 7. connect SENS_PIN_1 to GND, PUMP_PIN_1 contains collected charge voltage
  pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (SENS_PIN_1, LOW);
  // 8. read the charge voltage
  word value = analogRead (PUMP_PIN_1);
  // 9. prepare idle state, 
  //  both capacitor pins connected to VCC via pullup resistor
  pinMode (SENS_PIN_1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (PUMP_PIN_1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  return value;
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin (115200);
}

void loop(void) {
  word value1 = readCapSensor_1();
  Serial.println (value1);
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful

Comment: I will go for the second option. Will I be able to initiate the sound with the capacitive sensors rather than the push buttons on the arduino?

Comment: @Ark4747 I'm sure you will find the place in the demo code where the button is checked and the play command is sent to the module. You will write another condition check reading the sensor, whatever this will be. Do you want to buy a touch sensor module or solder one from discrete components?

Comment: Which is cheaper?

Comment: Actually another solution is to use IR sensors instead. Probably TSOP 1738 and a diode instead of a capcitive sensor. Will the setup with the speaker be the same?

Comment: @Ark4747 The above one is the cheapest I know, 10 ct without protection ;)

Comment: haha thanks I'll risk it